# Uniqueness for the wave equation on an interval

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

We search to prove that the following problem admits a unique solution.
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}= a^2 \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\\
u(0,t)=u(l,t)=0\\
u(x,0)=f(x)\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=g(x)
\end{cases}
$$
For this, we suppose that there exist two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$, et put  $v(x,t)=u_1(x,t)-u_2(x,t)$, and we prouve that $v(x,t)=0$ for all $(x,t)$.
 $v$ satisfies the equation: 
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} - a^2 \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}=0$$
By multipliynig by $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t}$, and integring on x, we found
$$
\displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} dx - a^2 \displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} dx=0
$$
By integration the term $\displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial f} dx$, on trouve
$$
[\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t}(l,t) \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}(l,t)]_0^l - \displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}) dx
$$

What we can do after this? 
Thank's for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you decided to perform these manipulations, but it seems you are considering the energy method. The energy for this equation is $$E(t)=\int_0^l (v_t^2+a^2v_x^2)\,dx$$ which is basically the sum of kinetic and potential energy. Differentiate with respect to time, apply the PDE, and integrate one of the terms by parts: you will get zero. This shows the energy is constant. Since it was zero initially, it stays equal to zero. This implies the function $v$ is constant, as desired.

Comment: who is $v_t^2$? it's $(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t})^2$?

Comment: Yes, the square of the $t$-derivative.